# Improve readability for long javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would be a better way to format the following, which is currently in one run-on line:

```
$(this).siblings().last().append('<span class="territory"> ' + territory + ' <a href="#;" class="remove-territory delete" data-territory_code="' + territory + '" data-task_id="' + task_id + '">x</a>,</span>')
```

Comment: Each place where you use + you could put it on a new line, or you could build the whole thing as an array then join it after, etc.

Comment: Or you could use jQuery to create the elements instead of using an HTML string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use array joining, because it's easier to read.

```
$(this)
    .siblings()
        .last()
            .append([
                '<span class="territory"> ',
                territory,
                ' <a href="#;" class="remove-territory delete" data-territory_code="',
                territory,
                '" data-task_id="',
                task_id,
                '">x</a>,</span>'
            ].join(''))
```

Or by creating elements with jQuery:

```
var $span = $('<span>')
                .addClass('territory')
                .text(' ' + territory),
    $link = $('<a>')
                .attr({
                    'href': '#',
                    'data-territory_code': territory,
                    'data-task_id': task_id
                })
                .addClass('remove-territory delete')
                .text('x');

$span.append($link).append(',');

$(this)
    .siblings()
        .last()
            .append($span);
```

Comment: Calling `Array.join` to generate the string vs just appending the string is faster?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker it's Array.join vs string concatenation, in both cases you're appending the string. http://jsperf.com/javascript-array-join-vs-string-concat/5

Comment: @KevinB: Admittedly I missed that string concatenation was going on in the OP. I still take issue with the statement about `Array.join` being  faster though. in the JSPerf it looks like the difference is negligible--and in many cases string concatenation actually looks faster.

Comment: I have removed my comment about performance. I was under the impression that the gain was greater.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Agreed, concatenation is faster, even if only by a little bit. Maybe the "faster" part of the answer should just be removed, since speed isn't something that was mentioned in the question anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer using jQuery to create the tags and set the attributes.

```
$(this).siblings().last().append($('<span>')
                                  .addClass('territory')
                                  .append(territory)
                                  .append($('<a>')
                                           .attr({ href: '#;', data-territory_code: territory, data-task_id: task_id })
                                           .addClass('remove-territory delete')
                                           .html('x'))
                                  .append(','));
```